# What lens properties define the Fourier transformation that the lens perfoms on a laser beam?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, laser, lenses

When a laser beam goes through a lens, its beam profile is transformed according to a Fourier-Transformation.
Could you tell me which properties of the lens define the Fourier-Transformation?
Is it "just" the focal length? Or is it the aperture? And/or something else?

In particular, I am searching a lens that does the inverse Fourier-Transformation that my F-Theta lens in a laser scanner system does. I know already from an answer to another question by John Renny, that "the same lens" can be used, to act effectively as its own inverse Fourier-Transformation for the beam profile.
So that second part of my question comes down to asking: What properties of my F-Theta lens define the Fourier-transformation that it does? ...so that I can find an equivalent lens for the inverse Fourier-Transformation of the F-Theta lens.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that a lens can do a Fourier transform is a combination of the fact that any optical field can be represented as a [plane-wave expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_optics) (an expansion in terms of plane waves, which looks just like an inverse Fourier transform) and the fact that a lens will focus a plane wave to a point in the back focal plane at a point that is linearly related to the propagation direction of that plane wave. This is more or less true for any lens, but if you want to have the best result then you want to pick a lens (or lens system) that will produce a flat back focal plane, as opposed to one that produces some field curvature.

Comment: This is unfortunately not addressing my question:
Which lens properties (focal length? aperture? other?) determine the fourier transformation that the lens does to the beam profile?

Comment: None of those properties *determine* the Fourier transformation. As I explained, the only "property" that is responsible is its ability to focus a plane wave to a point.

Comment: The focal length determines the scaling of the output in the Fourier Transform plane (the back focal plane of the lens). The aperture determines how well your sensor, at the Fourier Plane, can resolve the angles between plane waves.